# print only oldest month

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I make script to login to server and execute command.
and i want to print only the oldest month of the files.

```
from netmiko import Netmiko
from datetime import datetime
now = (datetime.now()).strftime('%b')
oldest = 'May'
LS = CONNECT.send_command("ls -tGg /root/backup | awk '{print $4, $7}'")
result = LS.split('/n')
```

here sample of `print(LS)`

```
May File1
May File2
Jun File3
Jun File4
Jul File5
```

So, i want to print the oldest file, in this case is `File1` `File2`
and here the example script

```
for i in result:
    file = i.split()
        if file[0] == oldest:
        print(file[1])
```

but on this script i manually assign the oldest month.
how can i track the oldest month automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
import os

files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)

oldest=files[0]

newest=files[-1]
```

Note: replace path with your dir path

Comment: its error
path = '/root/backup'
 files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 65, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cisco_backup.log'

actually module os, will execute command in local system, but i want to execute in remote system..

Comment: Please replace 'path' variable to '/root/backup' in 'os.listdir' function

Comment: @Fixlensmith Please use the above code in my new Answer. That works!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

months = ["Unknown",
              "January",
              "Febuary",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "July",
              "August",
              "September",
              "October",
              "November",
              "December"]

```
result=['May File1','May File2','Jun File3','Jun File4']
set1= set()
for i in result:
    file = i.split()
    set1.add(months.index(file[0]))
min_val = min(set1)
val=months[min_val]
print("\n".join(s.split()[1] for s in result if val.lower() in s.lower()))
```

Change the month list names as per your result